# Fuzzy logic matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, string-matching

So, I'm looking at implementing Fuzzy logic matching in my company and having trouble getting good results. For starters, I'm trying to match up Company names with those on a list supplied by other companies. 
My first attempt was to use soundex, but it looks like soundex only compares the first few sounds in the company name, so longer company names were too easily confused for one another.
I'm now working on my second attempt using the levenstein distance comparison. It looks promising, especially if I remove the punctuation first. However, I'm still having trouble finding duplicates without too many false positives.
One of the issues I have is companies such as widgetsco vs widgets inc. So, if I compare the substring of the length of the shorter name, I also pickup things like BBC University and CBC University campus. I suspect that a score using a combination of distance and longest common substring may be the solution.
Has anyone managed to build an algorithm that does such a matching with limited false positives?

Comment: The only matching I have ever had to do was based on substring matching e.g. BBC Uni and BBC University. This assumes that the starting part of the string is the same amongs all duplicates. For cases like: widgets inc I would first strip out entity type abbreviations. If you have other related data e.g. Company address, company CEO, then this too, can be compared to produce a score of the likelihood that two companies are the same. I would focus on normalising the data first (by removing fluff) before trying to actually compare it.

Comment: Removing the fluff is typically a good practice no matter what algorithm you use.

Comment: I will elaborate on normalising data. For cases like "Smith & Wesson" being matched to "Smith and Wesson" I would convert all "&" to "and" for the purposes of a match. I would also try to strip out entity types and their abbrevations (inc. co.) and check if this gives false positives. If data has more complex constructs e.g. "CompanyA trading as CompanyB", then they need to be parsed. IMO, fuzzy matching well structured data like company names is a wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Have you read similar SO questions? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Match names while importing data? Or correct user misspellings?  SQL Server's database engine doesn't provide fuzzy matching. Even full text search doesn't work well to match misspelled names. SSIS *does* provide fuzzy lookup and fuzzy grouping operators, which is great for importing data, useless for correcting user errors

Answer (score 1):

We have had good results on name and address matching using a Metaphone function created by Lawrence Philips.  It works in a similar way to Soundex, but creates a sound/consonant pattern for the whole value.  You may find this useful in conjunction with some other techniques, especially if you can strip some of the fluff like 'co.' and 'inc.' as mentioned in other comments:

```
create function [dbo].[Metaphone](@str as nvarchar(70), @KeepNumeric as bit = 0)
returns nvarchar(25)
    /*
    Metaphone Algorithm

    Created by Lawrence Philips.
    Metaphone presented in article in "Computer Language" December 1990 issue.

                 *********** BEGIN METAPHONE RULES ***********
     Lawrence Philips' RULES follow:
     The 16 consonant sounds:
                                                 |--- ZERO represents "th"
                                                 |
          B  X  S  K  J  T  F  H  L  M  N  P  R  0  W  Y
     Drop vowels

    Exceptions:
    Beginning of word: "ae-", "gn", "kn-", "pn-", "wr-"   ----> drop first letter
    Beginning of word: "wh-"                              ----> change to "w"
    Beginning of word: "x"                                ----> change to "s"
    Beginning of word: vowel or "H" + vowel               ----> Keep it

    Transformations:
    B ----> B       unless at the end of word after "m", as in "dumb", "McComb"
    C ----> X       (sh) if "-cia-" or "-ch-"
            S       if "-ci-", "-ce-", or "-cy-"
                    SILENT if "-sci-", "-sce-", or "-scy-"
            K       otherwise
            K       "-sch-"
    D ----> J       if in "-dge-", "-dgy-", or "-dgi-"
            T       otherwise
    F ----> F
    G ---->         SILENT if   "-gh-" and not at end or before a vowel
                                "-gn" or "-gned"
                                "-dge-" etc., as in above rule
            J       if "gi", "ge", "gy" if not double "gg"
            K       otherwise
    H ---->         SILENT  if after vowel and no vowel follows
                            or "-ch-", "-sh-", "-ph-", "-th-", "-gh-"
            H       otherwise
    J ----> J
    K ---->         SILENT if after "c"
            K       otherwise
    L ----> L
    M ----> M
    N ----> N
    P ----> F       if before "h"
            P       otherwise
    Q ----> K
    R ----> R
    S ----> X       (sh) if "sh" or "-sio-" or "-sia-"
            S       otherwise
    T ----> X       (sh) if "-tia-" or "-tio-"
            0       (th) if "th"
                    SILENT if "-tch-"
            T       otherwise
    V ----> F
    W ---->         SILENT if not followed by a vowel
            W       if followed by a vowel
    X ----> KS
    Y ---->         SILENT if not followed by a vowel
            Y       if followed by a vowel
    Z ----> S
    */


as
begin
declare @Result varchar(25)
        ,@str3  char(3)
        ,@str2  char(2)
        ,@str1  char(1)
        ,@strp  char(1)
        ,@strLen tinyint
        ,@cnt   tinyint

set @strLen = len(@str)
set @cnt = 0
set @Result = ''

-- Preserve first 5 numeric values when required
if @KeepNumeric = 1
    begin
        set @Result = case when isnumeric(substring(@str,1,1)) = 1
                            then case when isnumeric(substring(@str,2,1)) = 1
                                    then case when isnumeric(substring(@str,3,1)) = 1
                                            then case when isnumeric(substring(@str,4,1)) = 1
                                                    then case when isnumeric(substring(@str,5,1)) = 1
                                                                then left(@str,5)
                                                                else left(@str,4)
                                                                end
                                                    else left(@str,3)
                                                    end
                                            else left(@str,2)
                                            end
                                    else left(@str,1)
                                    end
                            else ''
                            end

        set @str = right(@str,len(@str)-len(@Result))
    end

--Process beginning exceptions
set @str2 = left(@str,2)

if @str2 = 'wh'
    begin
        set @str  = 'w' + right(@str , @strLen - 2)
        set @strLen =   @strLen - 1
    end
else
    if @str2 in('ae', 'gn', 'kn', 'pn', 'wr')
        begin
            set @str = right(@str , @strLen - 1)
            set @strLen = @strLen - 1
        end



set @str1 = left(@str,1)

if @str1 =  'x' 
    set @str  = 's' + right(@str , @strLen - 1)
else
    if @str1 in ('a','e','i','o','u')
        begin
            set @str = right(@str, @strLen - 1)
            set @strLen = @strLen - 1
            set @Result = @Result + @str1
        end

while @cnt <= @strLen
    begin
        set @cnt = @cnt + 1
        set @str1 = substring(@str,@cnt,1)

        set @strp = case when @cnt <> 0
                        then substring(@str,(@cnt-1),1)
                        else ' '
                        end

        -- Check if the current character is the same as the previous character.
        -- If we are keeping numbers, only compare non-numeric characters.
        if case when @KeepNumeric = 1 and @strp = @str1 and isnumeric(@str1) = 0 then 1
                when @KeepNumeric = 0 and @strp = @str1 then 1
                else 0
                end = 1
            continue    -- Skip this loop

        set @str2 = substring(@str,@cnt,2)

        set @Result = case when @KeepNumeric = 1 and isnumeric(@str1) = 1
                                then @Result + @str1
                            when @str1 in('f','j','l','m','n','r')
                                then @Result + @str1
                            when @str1 = 'q'
                                then @Result + 'k'
                            when @str1 = 'v'
                                then @Result + 'f'
                            when @str1 = 'x'
                                then @Result + 'ks'
                            when @str1 = 'z'
                                then @Result + 's'
                            when @str1 = 'b'
                                then case when @cnt = @strLen
                                            then case when substring(@str,(@cnt - 1),1) <> 'm'
                                                    then @Result + 'b'
                                                else @Result
                                                end
                                        else @Result + 'b'
                                        end
                            when @str1 = 'c'
                                then case when @str2  = 'ch' or substring(@str,@cnt,3) = 'cia'
                                            then @Result + 'x'
                                            else case when @str2 in('ci','ce','cy') and @strp <> 's'
                                                    then @Result + 's'
                                                    else @Result + 'k'
                                                    end
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'd'
                                then case when substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('dge','dgy','dgi')
                                            then @Result + 'j'
                                            else @Result + 't'
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'g'
                                then case when substring(@str,(@cnt - 1),3) not in ('dge','dgy','dgi','dha','dhe','dhi','dho','dhu')
                                            then case when @str2 in('gi', 'ge','gy')
                                                    then @Result + 'j'
                                                    else case when @str2 <> 'gn' or (@str2 <> 'gh' and @cnt+1 <> @strLen)
                                                                then @Result + 'k'
                                                                else @Result
                                                                end
                                                    end
                                            else @Result
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'h'
                                then case when @strp not in ('a','e','i','o','u') and @str2 not in ('ha','he','hi','ho','hu')
                                            then case when @strp not in ('c','s','p','t','g')
                                                        then @Result + 'h'
                                                        else @Result
                                                        end
                                            else @Result
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'k'
                                then case when @strp <> 'c'
                                            then @Result + 'k'
                                            else @Result
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'p'
                                then case when @str2 = 'ph'
                                            then @Result + 'f'
                                            else @Result + 'p'
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 's'
                                then case when substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('sia','sio') or @str2 = 'sh'
                                            then @Result + 'x'
                                            else @Result + 's'
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 't'
                                then case when substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('tia','tio')
                                            then @Result + 'x'
                                            else case when @str2 = 'th'
                                                        then @Result + '0'
                                                        else case when substring(@str,@cnt,3) <> 'tch'
                                                                    then @Result + 't'
                                                                    else @Result
                                                                    end
                                                        end
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'w'
                                then case when @str2 not in('wa','we','wi','wo','wu')
                                            then @Result + 'w'
                                            else @Result
                                            end
                            when @str1 = 'y'
                                then case when @str2 not in('ya','ye','yi','yo','yu')
                                            then @Result + 'y'
                                            else @Result
                                            end
                            else @Result
                            end
    end

return @Result

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like Levenshtein Distance or another string comparison algorithm. You may want to take a look at this project on Codeplex.

http://fuzzystring.codeplex.com/

Comment: I like Levenshtein Distance but the problem is that it is not "fuzzy".  The distance between 'CBC University' and 'CBC Univer' is 4 even though they are probably the same place.  This SO post has a nice "fuzzy" Levenshtein [SQL Server Fuzzy Search with Percentage of match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259117/sql-server-fuzzy-search-with-percentage-of-match)

Comment: @user918967 it *is* fuzzy*. `CBC University` is farther apart from `CBC Univer`  than `CBC Universit`. The answers in the link show a typical Levenshtein implementation. Funny thing - I covered the alternatives in the question comments!

Comment: @Yobik that project migrated to github a long time ago. The correct link is https://github.com/kdjones/fuzzystring

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Access?  If so, consider the '*' character, without the quotes.  If you're using SQL Server, use the '%' character.  However, this really isn't fuzzy logic, it's really the Like operator.  If you really need fuzzy logic, export your data-set to Excel and load the AddIn from the URL below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Read the instructions very carefully.  It definitely works, and it works great, but you need to follow the instructions, and it's not completely intuitive.  The first time I tried it, I didn't follow the instructions, and I wasted a lot of time trying to get it to work.  Eventually I figured it out, and it worked great!!

Comment: The question is about fuzzy matching, not wildcards. It's about matching `This Guy` and `This uy`

Answer (score 0):

I found success implementing a function I found here on Stack Overflow that would find the percentage of strings that match. You can then adjust tolerance till you get an appropriate amount of matches/mismatches. The function implementation will be listed below, but the gist is including something like this in your query.

```
DECLARE @tolerance DEC(18, 2) = 50;
WHERE dbo.GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(first_table.name, second_table.name) > @tolerance
```

Credit for the following percent matching function goes to *Dragos Durlut, Dec 15 '11*.
The credit for the LEVENSHTEIN function was included in the code by *Dragos Durlut*.

[T-SQL Get percentage of character match of 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518695/t-sql-get-percentage-of-character-match-of-2-strings)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching]
(
    @string1 NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@string2 NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @levenShteinNumber INT

    DECLARE @string1Length INT = LEN(@string1)
    , @string2Length INT = LEN(@string2)
    DECLARE @maxLengthNumber INT = CASE WHEN @string1Length > @string2Length THEN @string1Length ELSE @string2Length END

    SELECT @levenShteinNumber = [dbo].[LEVENSHTEIN] (   @string1  ,@string2)

    DECLARE @percentageOfBadCharacters INT = @levenShteinNumber * 100 / @maxLengthNumber

    DECLARE @percentageOfGoodCharacters INT = 100 - @percentageOfBadCharacters

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @percentageOfGoodCharacters

END




-- =============================================     
-- Create date: 2011.12.14
-- Description: http://blog.sendreallybigfiles.com/2009/06/improved-t-sql-levenshtein-distance.html
-- =============================================

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LEVENSHTEIN](@left  VARCHAR(100),
                                @right VARCHAR(100))
returns INT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @difference    INT,
              @lenRight      INT,
              @lenLeft       INT,
              @leftIndex     INT,
              @rightIndex    INT,
              @left_char     CHAR(1),
              @right_char    CHAR(1),
              @compareLength INT

  SET @lenLeft = LEN(@left)
  SET @lenRight = LEN(@right)
  SET @difference = 0

  IF @lenLeft = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @difference = @lenRight

        GOTO done
    END

  IF @lenRight = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @difference = @lenLeft

        GOTO done
    END

  GOTO comparison

  COMPARISON:

  IF ( @lenLeft >= @lenRight )
    SET @compareLength = @lenLeft
  ELSE
    SET @compareLength = @lenRight

  SET @rightIndex = 1
  SET @leftIndex = 1

  WHILE @leftIndex <= @compareLength
    BEGIN
        SET @left_char = substring(@left, @leftIndex, 1)
        SET @right_char = substring(@right, @rightIndex, 1)

        IF @left_char <> @right_char
          BEGIN -- Would an insertion make them re-align?
              IF( @left_char = substring(@right, @rightIndex + 1, 1) )
                SET @rightIndex = @rightIndex + 1
              -- Would an deletion make them re-align?
              ELSE IF( substring(@left, @leftIndex + 1, 1) = @right_char )
                SET @leftIndex = @leftIndex + 1

              SET @difference = @difference + 1
          END

        SET @leftIndex = @leftIndex + 1
        SET @rightIndex = @rightIndex + 1
    END

  GOTO done

  DONE:

  RETURN @difference
  END
```

Note: If you need to compare two or more fields (which I don't think you do) you can add another call to the function in the WHERE clause with a minimum tolerance. I also found success averaging the percentMatching and comparing it against a tolerance.

```
DECLARE @tolerance DEC(18, 2) = 25; 
--could have multiple different tolerances for each field (weighting some fields as more important to be matching)
DECLARE @avg_tolerance DEC(18, 2) = 50;

WHERE AND dbo.GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(first_table.name, second_table.name) > @tolerance
      AND dbo.GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(first_table.address, second_table.address) > @tolerance
      AND (dbo.GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(first_table.name, second_table.name)
            + dbo.GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(first_table.address, second_table.address)
           ) / 2 > @avg_tolerance
```

The benefit of this solution is the tolerance variables can be specific per field (weighting the importance of certain fields matching) and the average can insure general matching across all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest, you make sure that you can't match on any other attribute and company names are all you have(because fuzzy matching is bound to give you some false positives). If you want to go ahead with fuzzy matching you could use the following steps:

1. Remove all stop words from the text. For example : Co, Inc etc.
2. If your database is very large, make use of an indexing method such as blocking or sorted neighbourhood indexing.
3. Finally compute the fuzzy score using the Levenshtein distance. You could use the token_set_ratio or partial_ratio functions in Fuzzywuzzy.

Also, I found the following video which aims to solve the same problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRAqIjXaZvw

The Nanonets blog also contains several resources on the subject that could potentially be helpful.