# Fuzzy string matching SQL - words in different order

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, pattern-matching, fuzzy-search

How to match strings which are not exact and have a different order of words. Usually the strings have similar digit patterns but the words may be in different order.

For example, I would consider a good matching of strings:

**Target string**: `Apple 10mg/51L Tail`

**Test string**: `Tail 10mg/51L Apple` (just shuffle of words, correct spelling)

I would also consider a good match between the following strings:

**Test string**: `51L MissleadingLENWord ObfuscateTail 10mg Apple` (all the words of target string can be found in the test string if we check each word one by one with LIKE clause i.e. "Tail" of target string can be found in test string in word "ObfuscateTail").

I would like to see the solution of this problem in the function returning the percentage number, which means how similar the strings are - zero - the strings are different, 100% both strings are the same.

Which algorytm should I use? Best if it could be implemented with SQL Server.

I could find some algorithms proposed here: [Fuzzy matching using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql).
Is the **Levenshtein** distance algorithm mentioned in leading answer appropriate for mixed order of words?

Comment: You need to look into full text search for whatever database you are using.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259117/sql-server-fuzzy-search-with-percentage-of-match

Comment: I assume, that you need a solution for `T-SQL` (due to the given link). Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My existing answer was given about 4 Werks ago. What's wrong with It? It would help to tell your audience what you expect.TSQL is - quite probably - the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @Shnugo I just wanted to see alternative approaches and test different algorithms. Would you consider to modify your solution into either scalar function with two parameters (string1, string2) or TVF where input of two compared columns is taken from a given table? Then it would be more applicable for broader audience.

Comment: if you are looking for alternative approach then i will suggest throw more sample of Target string and Test string clearly indicating what which qualify and which do not qualify and in proper order.How much data will be process at one time,say you pass single Test String or multiple Test String ?

Comment: Ive done it multple times by either using cosine similarity or jaccard index . Ive coded them as a function in sql, and then called them when needed . .

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin It is a very bad idea to create a function with two strings as parameters. This will get absolutely slow. The same actions, especially the string splitting, will be done multiple times. It is easy actually. The given code needs not more than a few tiny changes, but this function you ask for is the wrong approach.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin See the updated answer... You can check the function and tell us something about the performance. I'm pretty sure this will be very bad...

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin The bounty you've offered is lost, as you neither accepted an answer nor awarded one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found anything that could measure the shuffling of words in a string. For a shuffling of letters I ended up using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26389197/1903793

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [FuzzyString]
FROM 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
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Levenshtein](@S1 [nvarchar](200), @S2 [nvarchar](200))
RETURNS [float] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [FuzzyString].[StoredFunctions].[HaBoLevenshtein]
GO
```

Example how to use it:

```
select [dbo].[Levenshtein] ('Apple', 'Appleee')
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as the words are separated (blank, `/` or any other delimiter), this can be done with a string splitter and a hit count, but you won't find "Tail" in "ObfuscateTail". You'd need some *CamelCase parsing* additionally...

A rather easy workaround would be a `LIKE` search with all the fragments, but this might bring back to much - and (for sure!) this won't be fast...

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourTarget VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('51L MissleadingLENWord ObfuscateTail 10mg Apple')
                              ,('Some other 51L with differing words');

DECLARE @search VARCHAR(100)='Apple 10mg/51L Tail';

WITH Parted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@search,' ','/'),'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SearchFragmentsXML
)
,AllSearchWords AS
(
    SELECT frgmnt.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Frg 
    FROM Parted 
    CROSS APPLY SearchFragmentsXML.nodes(N'/x') AS A(frgmnt)
)
SELECT ID
      ,COUNT(*) AS CountHits
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AllSearchWords) AS CountFragments
FROM @mockupTable AS t
INNER JOIN AllSearchWords AS Frgs ON t.YourTarget LIKE '%' + Frgs.Frg + '%'
GROUP BY ID;
```

The result

```
ID  CountHits   CountFragments
1   4           4
2   1           4
```

The closer the "count of hits" is to the "count of fragments" the better.

### UPDATE: A function (not recommended)

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.YourSearch;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourSearch(@SearchIn VARCHAR(MAX), @SearchFor VARCHAR(100)='Apple 10mg/51L Tail')
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rslt DECIMAL(10,4) =
(
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / MAX(SearchFragmentsXML.value('count(/x[text()])','float'))
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchFor,' ','/'),'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SearchFragmentsXML
    ) AS Parted
    CROSS APPLY SearchFragmentsXML.nodes(N'/x') AS A(frgmnt)
    WHERE @SearchIn LIKE '%' + frgmnt.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') + '%'
);

RETURN @rslt;
END
GO

DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourTarget VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('51L MissleadingLENWord ObfuscateTail 10mg Apple')
                              ,('Some other 51L with differing words');

SELECT t.*
      ,dbo.YourSearch(t.YourTarget,'Apple 10mg/51L Tail') AS HitCoeff
FROM @mockupTable AS t;
```

The result

```
ID  YourTarget                                          HitCoeff
1   51L MissleadingLENWord ObfuscateTail 10mg Apple     1
2   Some other 51L with differing words                 0,25
```

**Hint:** It would help a lot, if you'd use a physical table with a `SessionID`, where you fill in the fragments of your search string. Then you pass the `SessionID` to the function and grab the fragments from there. This would - at least - avoid repeated splittings and could use result caching.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Remin,how much rows will be process at a time.This solution is also good. Levenshtein algorithm can be implemented here too if data process will be less .Or you can have both.for example this script shortlist 10 rows then in interface you can provide weightage logic for sorting so that it is fast.Levenshtein logic is good too.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for what is often called phrase matching.

Fuzzy in the word and on the words gets messy fast.

All approaches start with splitting the words.

You could use a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance but based on words not characters within the word.  You could just take the hash of the word.  Not perfect but hash based would be much faster.

The common best practice here is [tf–idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).  This is used by Lucene.  You may think it is kind of intense but I did it on a library of 1 million documents using up to the first 100,000 words and it finds ranked matches in less than 1 second.   Again you don't get fuzzy in the word.

[Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is another option.

Fuzzy in the words you could Levenshtein against every word and take the smallest then do some sum.  I don't recommend this route.